# Approximation of a $C^3$ function by a degree two polynomial.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

**Question:** Let f be a three times continuously differentiable real valued function on $(0,5)$ such that its third derivative $f'''(x)=\frac{1}{100}$ for all $x\in(0,5)$. If $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq2$ such that $P(1)=f(1),P(2)=f(2)$ and $P(3)=f(3)$ then what is the value of $|f(4)-P(4)|$?

**My solution:** I can write $f(x)$ as a cubic polynomial by applying Fundamental theorem of calculus(i.e., $f(x)-f(x_0)=\int_{x_0}^{x}f'(x)dx$) Then assuming a polynomial form for $P$, and using the given relation between $f$ and $P$, we get a system of equation for the coefficients of $f$ and $P$. And solving these equations, we get the answer.

But this solution becoming very lengthy. So, does anyone have any tricky solution for this problem? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In $(0,5)$, we have that $g(x)=f(x)-P(x)$ is a cubic polynomial with roots at $1$, $2$, and $3$. This means $g(x)=A(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$ for some $A\in\mathbb R$. Taking three derivatives and noting that $g^{(3)}(x)=f^{(3)}(x)$ since $P$ is only quadratic, we have $A=1/600$ (remember the third derivative will introduce a $3!$). Now $$|g(4)|=\frac{1}{600}(4-1)(4-2)(4-3)=\frac{1}{100}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $f$ is a polynomial of degree $3$, knowing that the third derivative is a constant allows you to write down the general form of the function directly:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{600} x^3 + a x^2 + b x^2 + c x + d.$$

(Try taking the third derivative to see!)

Now just solve for $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ given your constraints and conditions.

Comment: Ooops.... thanks.